# Can unsuccessful Area 51 proposals get resurrected after some time?

Tags: discussion, area-51

The whole idea of Area 51 and giving chance to people to propose their SE is truly amazing and probably the feature of SE I can give most praise to ( otherwise most praise goes to ever hardworking moderators ).

It is only natural that Area 51 ideas that don't receive enough attention and activity are deemed "not the right stuff" for the SE network. However, some ideas that truly are great don't shine because of the inactivity during the testing phases - but doesn't mean the opposite can't happen in some years hence.

We all know about certain topics and areas that strike the world and gain instant popularity and recognition. But there are also topics and areas that do it by a steeper path, for which it takes a longer time to achieve (near?) equal popularity.

Therefore my question is : Can some 'failed' Area 51 proposals get another chance after some time ?

Comment: I though you just created a new proposal for that. Is that not allowed?

Comment: @Mat - I didn't come across any information whether it is as simple as that. If you are certain about it, you can give it as an actual answer to my Q.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think I saw that somewhere. Searching.

Comment: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13066/is-programmation-stack-overflow-in-french-the-same-as-the-closed-proposal-s - evidence that this happens. Not sure about the official rules though.

Comment: Yes. Arduino : [1](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino) [2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) Gamification : [1](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification) [2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61762/gamification) Economics : [1](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) [2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics)

Comment: [Freelancing SE](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com) is another one that was given a second chance and is now in public beta. Like Chris says, it's all about *you*. It's up to the community to make a site work. :)

Comment: The most recent example being Joomla (still in beta though).

Comment: And let's not forget Mathematica, which not only came back after being shutdown in the proposal stage, but also zoomed more or less straight through to graduation on their second attempt.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you starting a new site proposal that covers the same topics as a previously failed one.

**However**, you should make sure you address the reasons why the first proposal failed. Was it too broad or too narrow? Was it duplicating a site that already existed? Can you increase the participation?

Find out why the first proposal failed, address those issues and try again. You might have better luck the second time around.